# Javascript button disable and enabled using for particular time

Tags: javascript, html

newbie to java script , I want to do like when any one click on first Button,then second button is disabled for 30 seconds , after the enabled of second button, click on second button and third button visible to the user. I know simple disable enable buttons on tutorials Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="button" id="myBtn" value="My Button">

<p>Click the button below to disable the button above.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {

     document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **setTimeout** function to do it.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
     document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
     setTimeout(function(){
       document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = false;
     }, 5000);
}
</script>
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Ooops! @AlexG, I did not know :)

Comment: @balaG u have to edit your question 500 not working 5000 will work

Comment: @balaG and Read my question please i know how to disabled and enable

Answer (score 1):

Use setTimeout() function and variables to flag click status:

```
 setTimeout("myFunction();", 30000);
```

Answer (score 1):

see this plunker http://embed.plnkr.co/ZUmGoGEr2TYHlfPhUJgK/preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>

<input type="button" id="myBtn" value="My Button"  onclick="document.getElementById('thirdBtn').style.display='block'">
<input type="button" style="display:none;" id="thirdBtn" value="Third Button">
<p>Click the button below to disable the button above.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById('thirdBtn').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
     setTimeout(function(){

       document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = false;
     }, 30000);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```